# Accessing resources within a JAR file

Tags: java, file, resources, path

I'm trying to access resources that I have embedded in a JAR file. The class that needs to access a file is:

```
/worldEntities/factories/RoomFactory.class
```

and it tries to access:

```
/map-data/roomDescriptions.xml
```

To do this, I have added the following code to RoomFactory.class:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/map-data" + File.separator + "roomDescriptions.xml"));
```

When I execute the project in NetBeans, it works fine with no errors. However, when I attempt to run the code from the command line, by entering

```
java -jar Program.jar
```

I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null, and it points the code that I describe above.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Thomas

Comment: If you use File.separator, then you should use it consistently, including the leading slash. On the other hand, using it in getResourceAsStream call is wrong as this doesn't represent a native filesystem path. Just use a slash, it's guaranteed to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Name with `"-"` char are not valid Java package name. So `"map-data"` is not a valid package name.
2. Then `File.separator` could be different on different platforms. Use `"/"` in your code to be sure to use the valid package separator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you bundle the resource with the .jar, otherwise it won't be found

[This post](http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) should help on how to do it from NetBeans