# Access a file from within a jar on Windows

Tags: java, windows, jar

I am having trouble accessing a file within my Jar on Windows.  I do not have this problem when I run it on Unix.  I have created the jar both on Windows & Unix and it makes no difference.  Either way it does not run on Windows.

I ran the jar -tf command on my jar and the class I am running from is located in:  a/b/c/d/ClassOne.class.  The class I am looking for is located in my base directory of the jar:  ClassTwo.class

My code in this ClassOne looks like the following:

```
String path = File.separator + "myYAML.yml";
InputStream in = MetricCollector.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

My code breaks on the last line shown throwing a NullPointerException which I can only believe means it cannot find the path I have given it.  However, this exact code works great on my debugger and on Unix when I run the jar.

I have also tested the following paths:

1. `"myYAML.yml"`
2. `File.seperator + ".." + File.seperator + ".." + File.seperator + ".." + File.seperator + ".." + "myYAML.yml"`
3. `".." + File.seperator + ".." + File.seperator + ".." + File.seperator + ".." + "myYAML.yml"`

all to no avail.

I have used the following Stack Overflow posts to get as far as I can, but they do not seem to have an answer for me:  [How to reference a resource file correctly for JAR and Debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192661/how-to-reference-a-resource-file-correctly-for-jar-and-debugging), [Accessing resources within a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153790/accessing-resources-within-a-jar-file) and [Reading file from within JAR not working on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961233/reading-file-from-within-jar-not-working-on-windows)

Any additional help I would be extremely grateful for.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.separator` cannot work on Windows, it returns `\`. You need to use `/` as a separator regardless of the OS.

The [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) states

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

In other words, you must use `/`. This is further explained in the javadoc for [`ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to which `Class#getResource` delegates.

> The name of a resource is a /-separated path name that identifies the
>   resource.

If the resource is at the root of the classpath, use

```
InputStream in = MetricCollector.class.getResourceAsStream("/myYAML.yml");
```

Comment: To expand a bit more: when working with the `File` class you can *always* use the `/` in Java - even on Windows

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks for the answer and for explaining it in detail.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I understand that. I just wanted to add that you *can* use `/` even on Windows when working with the `File` class.